# Twitter Widget Not Always Loading

Tags: javascript, html, turbolinks

I have a basic Twitter Widget like this on a webpage:

```
<div class="twitter mobile-hide">
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TheStickyNoteEd" data-widget-id="722809724224151554">Tweets by @TheStickyNoteEd</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>
```

Sometimes, the widget will disappear only leaving a Link to the Twitter. I am just running the webpage locally on my hard drive. It does not seem to relate to domain restrictions as I have also deployed it here: http://beta.thestickynote.com/ and the problem continues to occur.

The site may ask you for a username/pass, just use this generic guest login.

User:beta
Pass: thestickynote

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be caused by the Domain restrictions of your browser to prevent cross site scripting. When running files locally, sometimes the browser considers each file its own "Domain" and so it will not allow the page to draw data from the Twitter server.

When this occurs, the fallback is to display the link to your Twitter account, as evidenced by the part of the markup:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TheStickyNoteEd" data-widget-id="722809724224151554">Tweets by @TheStickyNoteEd</a>
```

**Update**

This problem may be related to your use of Turbolinks. Turbolinks is a Javascript library which makes pages load faster, but it seems to break the Twitter widget's functionality, causing the fallback link to appear.

**Update 2**

Inline Javascript is not loaded when a page is fetched by AJAX, this is causing the widget not to load.

Comment: I just deployed pasted my code into a Rails app(main app is written rails with the exception of the widget) and deployed it to a production server. The problem seems to continue.

Comment: @AgentSpyname Can you reply with the link to the production server?

Comment: @AgentSpyname I believe that the problem in this case is that the full domain name is not registered as part of the Twitter widget. Can you register beta.thestickynote.com in Twitter and put the new widget into the site?

Comment: I can't find anything about registering a domain in the widget creation panel.

Comment: @AgentSpyname The Twitter Widget is active now in my browser. Is it working on your browser?

Comment: @AgentSpyname I think that I figured something out. It appears as though the widget works when the visitor first gets to the page, but then once he or she clicks on one of the tabs, the widget stops working.

Comment: @AgentSpyname I think that the problem is with Turbolinks. Can you try to disable Turbolinks, and see if the Twitter Widget loads correctly?

Comment: Just removed the turbolinks from the page.

Comment: Are you able to disable any type of AJAX page loading? The pages are still being loaded through AJAX.

Comment: I'll take a look around.

Comment: Can't find any thing involving the loading of AJAX Pages. I removed Turbolinks from the JS, the Gemfile and the application file. Nothing anywhere.

Comment: On my end it now seems to display the Twitter widget after page navigation without a problem. Is it working on your end?

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem because I was using Next.js to pre-render my pages.
so the solution was to put the `<script/>` inside the `<head></head>` of my html.

```
import Head from "next/head";

const TwitterWidget = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <script
          async
          src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
          charSet="utf-8"
        ></script>
      </Head>
      <a
        className="twitter-timeline"
        href="https://twitter.com/_THE_TIMLINE_URL_"
      >
        Tweets by _SOMEONE_
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TwitterWidget;
```

Not like this:

```
const TwitterWidget = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <a
        className="twitter-timeline"
        href="https://twitter.com/_THE_TIMLINE_URL_"
      >
        Tweets by _SOMEONE_
      </a>
      <script
          async
          src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
          charSet="utf-8"
        ></script>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TwitterWidget;
```

Comment: The same applies to instagram embeds, put the script on the Head

Comment: i love you man! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the widget as it was generated. After consulting in the Twitter dev forums I read a solution to add `twttr.widgets.load();` at the end of the script, which I see your widget code doesn't have. That is, try using

```
<div class="twitter mobile-hide">
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TheStickyNoteEd" data-widget-id="722809724224151554">Tweets by @TheStickyNoteEd</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs"); twttr.widgets.load();</script>
</div>
```